# Extracting dictionary from TensorFlow's built in history

Tags: python, bash, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm in the process of getting my feet wet with tensorflow. I've started and successfully run the MNIST classifier with layers [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers#building_the_cnn_mnist_classifier) on my computer, now my objective is to play around with the parameters of the tutorial program (step size, layer properties). To do this, I want to collect the data on each run of the convolutional neural network and see if I can learn something from the changes of the network's output based on the changes of the network's design.

At the end of each run of the program (CNN MNIST Classifier) tensorflow returns numerous lines labeling what the classifier is doing. This one caught my eye:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Saving dict for global step 161: accuracy = 0.1663,
global_step = 161, loss = 2.286773
```

Now, I can copy/screenshot this line every time I want to record my run, but I'd like to figure out how to access the dictionary where this data is being collected.

I've tried `find tensorflow` in my bash, this wasn't very helpful.

My question is:
How would I find the run history for this classifier? Can you give me any advice on how to record/access this information in the future?

Comment: Have you read that tutorial on [summaries and TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/summaries_and_tensorboard)? The instructions therein should be sufficient.

Comment: That's what i needed! Thank you. I'll post the exact answer after I figure it out totally.